etwas in den Status ... wechseln ODER etwas auf den Status ... wechseln?
Angenommen, es kann in einer ERP-Software ein darin angelegter Auftrag einen Status von mehreren annehmen. Welche Formulierung ist korrekt:

Ein Klick auf Schaltfläche A lässt den Auftrag in den Status 'Erledigt' wechseln.

Ein Klick auf Schaltfläche A lässt den Auftrag auf den Status 'Erledigt' wechseln.



Ich h"atte wohl "zum Status" benutzt, weil das in der Programmiererei von Markov-Prozessen wie in Pfeil in einem Verlaufs/Zustandsdiagram gekennzeichnet wird.

Ich würde hier in verwenden; auf ist meiner Meinung nach nur durch die Wendung wechseln auf wie in die Ampel wechselt auf Grün motiviert, da ist Status aber nicht sinnvoll integrierbar.
Zusätzlich kann man die Wendung

aus dem Zustand offen in den Zustand erledigt

zur Argumentation heranziehen.
Insgesamt halte ich den Satz für übermäßig technisch und würde eher formulieren:

Ein Klick auf Schaltfläche A markiert den Auftrag als "erledigt".

Dass das Tabellenfeld Status heißt, steht für den Benutzer nicht wirklich im Vordergrund, falls es überhaupt von Bedeutung ist.

Danke für die Antwort. Tatsächlich waren die Sätze so gewählt worden, um ein kurzes aber sinnvolles Szenario für die Frage zu bilden und sollen in dieser technischen Form wahrscheinlich nicht eingesetzt werden.
